# API for Changing a User Role in Desire2Learn

Tags: desire2learn

In the [user api docs](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html) it is mentioned that to change the user's role at the organization level we need to use the schema "PUT /d2l/api/lp/(D2LVERSION: version)/users/(D2LID: userId)"
This requires UpdateUserData JSON block as input, but the UpdateUserData JSON block does not have a role id in it. How, then, will we pass the new role of the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Role applies to a particular level in the organization so is not an intrinsic property of a user but rather property of the relationship between a user and the org or user and the org unit (department, course etc).

So you could delete and then create the user’s enrollment at the org level . (Id for the org level is retrieved with [org info call](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-organization-info) )

The operation to [delete the enrollment](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#delete--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-enrollments-orgUnits-%28D2LID-orgUnitId%29-users-%28D2LID-userId%29) is on the enrollment page.  And the operation to create the enrollment is on the same page.

However, it is NOT typical for a user to have no enrollment at the org level (e.g. if there was a connection interrupt between delete and create it is not clear what that state of not being enrolled in the org would mean)

I am not sure this fits your application, but, more typical than adding and removing enrollments at the org level is to add and remove them in a particular org level. That way the user always has a presence in the org, but, you can govern permissions via that org unit.